# How to use Bash array of globs with find?

Tags: bash

I have an array of globs that I want to feed to `find`.

My array is:

```
arr=('a*.txt' 'b[2-5].sh' 'ab?.doc')
```

Here what i tried:

```
find . -type f -name '${arr[@]}'
```

Here our array may contain many elements!
Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to search for multiple glob patterns with `find` isn't as straightforward as `find -name "${arr[@]}"`; you need something equivalent to:

```sh
find '(' -name 'a*.txt' -o -name 'b[2-5].sh' -o -name 'ab?.doc' ')'
```

<sup>**note:** the parenthesis aren't mandatory in your case but you'll need them for adding other operands like `-type f`</sup>

That said, if your starting point is a bash array containing your globs, then you could build the arguments of `find` like this:

```sh
arr=('a*.txt' 'b[2-5].sh' 'ab?.doc')

names=()
for glob in "${arr[@]}"
do
    [[ $names ]] && names+=( -o )
    names+=(-name "$glob")
done

find '(' "${names[@]}" ')'
```

Comment: Nice. I'd recommend initializing `names` before the loop to make sure it starts empty, with `names=()`.