# How to use variables in the find command

Tags: bash, find

I would like a loop because I have a lot of exclusions. The issue is that I don't know how to use variables to do it.

Here is my code:

```
tabSearch=("20220514*" "20220508*" "20220515*")
find . \( ! -name "${tabSearch[0]}" -a ! -name "${tabSearch[1]}" \)
```

The idea is to use as `-name $variable` as a needed with a loop but I have a syntax issue. Can you help me please?

Comment: The simplest method is to build another array with the `!`, `-a`, etc in addition to the patterns. See ["How to use Bash array of globs with find?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816051/how-to-use-bash-array-of-globs-with-find)

Comment: the logic of `\( ! -name X -a ! -name X -a ! -name Z \)` can be written as `! \( -name X -o -name Y -o -name Z \)`

Comment: as comment above: `( for glob in "${tabSearch[@]}"; do tests+=(! -name "$glob"); done; find \( "${tests[@]}" \) )` (`-a` is implied)

Comment: What do you mean by _syntax issue_? I don't see any syntax error in your command.

Answer (score -1):

Best to create the condition string separately, then insert into the command.

ALso best to keep each condition separate.  Find automatically considers such conditions as 'and'ed unless you specify "-o" .

```
#!/bin/sh

CONDS=""

for cond in '20220514*' '20220508*' '20220515*'
do
    CONDS="${CONDS} \( ! -name '${cond}' \)"
done

eval find . ${CONDS} -print
```

Comment: Why is it best to create the condition string separately? What's wrong with the code in the question?

Comment: Very old expression about doing things:  slice and dice.  In other words, keep distinct elements separate.  In this case, building the condition string separately from the command that will do things, so that what is being done is more clearly visible.