# Why "xargs find | xargs mv" and "xargs find -exec mv" work but produce error printouts "No such file or directory"?

Tags: macos, find, xargs, mv

I get error printouts when I use methods of (1) `xargs find | xargs mv` and (2) `xargs find -exec mv` to move files, but the moving of the files works as expected. I get no error printouts when I use (3) an intermediate variable, which is what I want.

Finding the inode numbers, which is what I'm doing with `stat` and `sed`, shouldn't be related to the problem.

I have condensed my problem into the following. Basically I want to get rid of the error printouts in both of Methods 1 and 2 (no piping to /dev/null please).

Note I'm on macOS, using BSD `stat`, and I'm also using `zsh`.

And I also know about `find -print0 | xargs -0`, I just wanted to condense the problem so that it's not as long. This is as condensed as I want to get.

###### Setup

Make test subdirectories (which are later moved by inode number).

```
mkdir -p "./testdir/dir"{1..4}
```

###### Method 1 - `xargs find | xargs mv`

Works to move the subdirectories, but with error printouts.

```
stat -s ./testdir/* | sed -E -n 's/.*st_ino=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | xargs -I abc find ./testdir/* -maxdepth 1 -inum abc | xargs -I {} mv {} ~/.Trash
```

Error printouts:

```
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir2: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir2: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir3: No such file or directory
```

###### Method 2 - `xargs find -exec mv`

Works to move the subdirectories, but with error printouts.

```
stat -s ./testdir/* | sed -E -n 's/.*st_ino=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | xargs -I abc find ./testdir/* -maxdepth 1 -inum abc -exec mv {} ~/.Trash \;
```

Error printouts:

```
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir2: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir2: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir3: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir1: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir2: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir3: No such file or directory
find: ./testdir/dir4: No such file or directory
```

###### Method 3 - intermediate variable

Works to move the subdirectories, but this time without error printouts, which is what I want.

```
dirs_to_move=$(stat -s ./testdir/* | sed -E -n 's/.*st_ino=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | xargs -I abc find ./testdir/* -maxdepth 1 -inum abc)
printf '%s\n' "$dirs_to_move" | xargs -I {} mv {} ~/.Trash
```

###### Question

How do I eliminate the error printouts from both of Methods 1 and 2? What is causing the printouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `find` is being told to search all 4 subdirectories, even after some of them have been deleted.

Detailed eplanation: The root problem is that the wildcard in the `xargs -I abc find ./testdir/* -maxdepth 1 ...` part gets expanded by the shell before any of the commands get run. So that part of the script becomes:

```
... | xargs -I abc find ./testdir/dir1 ./testdir/dir2 ./testdir/dir3 ./testdir/dir4 -maxdepth 1 ...
```

What happens then is the `stat | sed` part sends the first inode number to `xargs`, that runs `find`, `find` searches all 4 directories for the matching item, and either deletes it directly or sends its path to the next `xargs` for deletion.

Next, the `stat | sed` part sends the second inode number to `xargs`, that runs `find`, `find` searches all 4 directories... oops, hey, one of them's missing! So it prints an error message about ./testdir/dir1 not existing, searches the other three, and (one way or another) deletes the next one.

Next comes the third inode number, and this time neither ./testdir/dir1 nor ./testdir/dir2 exists, so you get two error messages. Etc etc etc.

(There's also an additional problem with the second one, where immediately after running the `mv` command, `find` then tries to search its contents, and oops it's gone. That's why you get more error messages that way. I think you might've wanted `-maxdepth 0` to keep it from trying to do that.)

Solution: I'm not sure what the larger context is, but my immediate reaction is that this is an overcomplex mess and as much as possible should be removed. But without knowing what can be changed without breaking the big picture, the minimal fix I see is to just have `find` search the entire testdir directory, rather than using a wildcard to list specific (wrong) subdirectories:

```
... | xargs -I abc find ./testdir -maxdepth 1 ...
```

(And note that in this form, `-maxdepth 1` is actually correct.)

Comment: The reason why I'm using this particular code with inodes is that I'm getting the "birth_time" from `stat` as well, and moving files based on birth_time.

Comment: Would it work to build a single `find` expression to find all of the files (/directories) in a single pass, rather than re-running `find` for each individual item? Something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71816051/how-to-use-bash-array-of-globs-with-find), but with `-inum` instead of `-name`.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, it looks like it works: `find . -maxdepth 1 -inum 16398053 -o -inum 16332612`, I might try concatenating command-words using an array if I have the time, thanks for the suggestion and answer.

Comment: @Aeronautix You'll need parentheses in order to combine it with `-exec`, like in the answer I linked. Something like `find . -maxdepth 1 \( -inum 16398053 -o -inum 16332612 \) -exec ...`